# Structure for Headless Drupal 8 and Angular

Tags: javascript, 8

I have been looking and can't find an answer to this relatively simple thing. In doing headless Drupal 8 with angular front-end, I was able to build an app in angular but it won't reach the Drupal endpoint as they are running on different ports (local development, :9000 and :80). I don't want to use CORS as that seems that it will introduce a host of security issues in production that I am not looking to deal with.

If I create the angular app with Drupal inside angular, will Drupal have access to LAMP - if its in the same location that has access to LAMP stack?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are third-party JS modules that allow proxying of a subpath on your app domain to an entirely different domain. One such example is [grunt-connect-proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-connect-proxy). This way, the browser will think it's hitting the same domain, when the proxy is actually forwarding it to the other domain. However, this will depend on your JS setup, which you didn't mention.

Alternatively, just enable CORS and work with it. It's as simple as adding the following to the remote domain's `.htaccess` (which in your case, Drupal's).

```
Header Set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```